# Windows generated blend file compatibility with Ubuntu OS

Tags: modeling, texturing

I created a character in windows os. My college is trying to open that very same file in ubuntu but blender keeps crashing. Anybody knows why!? I thought Blender files were compatible across platforms…

We are both using Blender 2.82

Thanks!

Comment: Hi peat. Blender files are supposed to be compatible across platforms. However, Blender 2.82 is still in Alpha! So two things may have happened: 1) you encountered a bug in an alpha version, which is to be expected (**"[They can be unstable and mess up your files](https://builder.blender.org/download/)"**); or 2) you don't have the exact same version: check the git hash that appears in the splash screen

Comment: You are right, they are different version:
windows: 502f01cc47ab
Linux: e0cd5b980fc5

I had everything automatically packed into .blend, etc, etc but didn't realize about the different versions (just saw that both were 2.82 and thought that was enough).
I've got a character rigged and ready to use. I need to use ubuntu. What would be the best option!? At this point I can only see myself doing everything from scratch in ubuntu. Is there any other options!?

Comment: I don't know honestly, it's trial and error from here. Unless you receive better answers, I'd start by trying: 1) opening the file on Ubuntu with 2.81. If it opens correctly, save it: you're now on a stable track. If it fails, 2) in Blender 2.81, in a empty file, append the scene or the object from your file. If it fails 3) open your b2.82, select and copy the object; open Blender 2.81 and paste it. In any case, your goal is to bring everything back to a stable version.

Comment: If you're having compatibility issues and loading the files crashes Blender, please report this on the bug tracker with the affected Blender version (in this case the Ubuntu version) and the .blend file that causes issues. The bug reporting can be started from Blender through *Help > Report a Bug* or by clicking [here](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/).

Comment: Robert Gützkow something interesting is going on right now. I've been trying blender 2.82 and 2.81 for Linux and they both crash every time I try viewport shading (material and render preview). This is not file related, it happens even when no file is loaded. As soon as you click in one of those, blender crashes.

With regards to my file, I'm now allow to open one of the version I did in windows in Blender 2.81 for Linux but I cannot save it and I cannot viewport shading (material and render preview). I'll try 2.8 for Linux and see what happens!

Comment: Thanks Nicola Sap! Looks like I'll have to start from scratch! Blender in Ubuntu is a bit unstable! I'll have to find a version that actually works in Ubuntu because 2.81 and 2.82 don't! I'll try 2.80!

Comment: I always use the latest version of Blender with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and all works very well 99% of the time. It looks like your system has some peculiar problems. It would be great if you could file bug reports for the weird behaviour you're seeing!

Comment: That's what I don't understand! I've got ubuntu 18.04 and I have try blender 2.80, 2.81 and 2.82. Viewport shading (material and render preview) doesn't work in any of those! Even when I'm not working in any of my files! Blender just crash! At this point I'm not sure if it's blender or something on my side...

Comment: @peat Sounds like an issue with your graphics driver or hardware not meeting the minimum requirements for Blender 2.8x. Please update you graphics driver and check if your the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) are fulfilled (especially the GPU requirements).

Comment: @Robert Gützkow in windows blender works fine. Drivers are up to date and I'm above minimum requirements! I'm only having these problems in Linux. So far I've try ubuntu and manjaro and the results are the same! That's why I'm so confuse! To me it doesn't make sense!

Comment: That's why you should ensure that the drivers are up-to-date on Linux and that the hardware meets the minimum requirements. How exactly are you testing this on Linux? Is it on the same hardware with dual boot, a VM or a different computer?

Comment: @Robert Gützkow same computer with dual boot. I haven't try a VM yet